# Haml render multiple partials in layout

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, partial, partials

How can I make the code indent correctly?

app/views/layouts/shared.html.haml:

```
= render :partial => "shared/head"
= yield
= render :partial => "shared/footer"
```

app/views/shared/_head.html.haml:

```
!!!XML
!!!1.1
%html{"xml:lang" => "pl", :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
  %head
    %title
      some title
  %body
    .container
```

app/views/shared/index.html.haml:

```
%p
  Hello World!
```

app/views/shared/_footer.html.haml:

```
.footer
  Some copyright text
```

Rendered HTML output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xml:lang='pl' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
  <head> 
    <title> 
      some title
    </title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div class='container'></div> 
  </body> 
</html> 
<p> 
  Hello World!
</p> 
<div id='footer'> 
 Some copyright text
</div>
```

Comment: Very well articulated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `app/views/layout` for that and `yield` the actual content:

[Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-layouts.htm)

*Update*

`app/views/layout/shared.html.haml`:

```
!!! 1.1
%html
  = render "shared/head"
  %body
    .container
      = yield
  = render "shared/foot"
```

Comment: When I want to use the same header partial on multiple layouts I must repeat it on all my layouts...not very DRY and not the "Ruby way"

Comment: layouts are exactly for your problem, if you have more layouts with the same subcontent render those part from the common places

Comment: I have placed an example above, a simple layout with included head and footer, but as you can see it doesn't work

Comment: As you can see on Your example, when You have more layouts, for each of them You need to copy the first 6 lines... ugly aproach

Comment: 6 lines is not a big price for using haml

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm pretty late to the party here, but perhaps someone else will encounter this and need to deal with the same problem (as I did this evening).

In my case, I have a more complex setup for the opening HTML tag, and several different layouts, so I didn't want all the repetition. My opening HTML tag has conditions for different  IE versions and originally looked something like this:

```
- # /app/views/layouts/shared/_head.html.haml

!!! 5
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
%html{ 'xml:lang' => 'en', lang: 'en', class: 'no-js'}
  <!--<![endif]-->
  %head
  - # and so on...
```

I was having the same problem with `</html>` terminating prematurely, so I ripped the HTML tag out of the _head partial (leaving the head tag there) and created the following helper to deal with the problem:

```
# /app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper
  def render_html_tag(&block)
    markup = capture_haml &block
    haml = Haml::Engine.new <<-HAML
!!! 5
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
%html{ 'xml:lang' => 'en', lang: 'en', class: 'no-js'}
  <!--<![endif]-->
  = markup
HAML

    obj = Object.new
    haml.def_method(obj, :render, :markup)
    obj.render(markup: markup)
  end
end
```

It's a little messy and perhaps it can be cleaned up a bit, but the main idea is to take advantage of the [haml engine's #def_method](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#def_method-instance_method), which allows the layout to look something like this:

```
- # /app/views/layout/application.html.haml

= render_html_tag do
  = render 'layouts/shared/head'
  %body
    = yield
  = render 'layouts/shared/footer'
```

Comment: I did not try it out. Seems a bit complex for a simple indentation. But I'll upvote anyway.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. The above shared template is a much better approach.